# I'm trying to control a NexusUI matrix button with the space bar. It will turn on when I press it once but not sure how to make it turn off again

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using a Javascript function to control whether a sequencer is on or off in NexusUI with the spacebar (key 32). It will turn on when I press it once but how do I make it turn off when I press it again, similar to when using a spacebar to control the state of a YouTube video. I'm not able to use Jquery for this.

```js
window.addEventListener("keydown", keyboardActions);

  function keyboardActions(key) {
   if (key.keyCode == 32) {
    sequencer.sequence(dial1.val.value);
    console.log(key);
   }
      else {
      sequencer.stop();
      }
  }
```

```html
<canvas nx="matrix" id="sequencer"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the running state of the sequencer in a variable and then query that state. Something like this:

```
window.addEventListener("keydown", keyboardActions);

var running = false;
function keyboardActions(key) {
    if (key.keyCode == 32) {
        if (!running) {
            sequencer.sequence(dial1.val.value);
            running = true;
        } else {
            sequencer.stop();
            running = false;
        }
    }
}
```